# debugger ignores input in function (Python)

Tags: python, debugging, input

im trying to debug this function. when it comes to the part of the input (choice = input) it redirects me to new files named parce.py and coedecs.py, and doesnt actually do anything or asks for an input
how can I assign an input to the debugger?

```
from wave_helper import *


def menu():
    VALID_CHOISES = [1,2,3,4]
    print('Welcome! What would you like to do?')
    print('1.Change wav file')
    print('2.Merge two wav files')
    print('3.Compose melody in wav format')
    print('4.Exit the program \n')
    print('Type the options number, followed by Enter')
    choice = int(input())
    while choice not in VALID_CHOISES:
        print('Invalid option.Please try again')
        choice = int(input())
return choice


def change_wav_file():
    choice = menu()
    if choice == 1:
        print('Please write the name of the file you would like to read')

change_wav_file()
```

Comment: What debugger do you use?

Comment: Btw. Your `menu()` call is incorrect. You should do `choice = menu()` and then `if choice == 1:`...

Comment: im using pycharm debugger @sashaaero

Comment: I tried by myself and it works for me. Pay attention that you should switch for Console tab instead of Debugger (in bottom frame)

Comment: what do you mean by switch?, do I get an option to set the input there?

Comment: There are 2 tabs: Debugger and Console. Your input is being awaited in Console tab.